# obj.playVideo is not a function error in firebug

Tags: javascript, flash

I am using this code :

```
var obj = swfobject.getObjectById("myytplayer");

console.debug(obj);

obj.playVideo();

//obj.pauseVideo();
```

When I run this, I get an error like:

```
obj.playVideo is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what type of element is `myytplayer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that problem.

When i deploy my web page on iis it's works fine. so for that problem just host your webpage and it's works fine

tnx

Answer (score 0):

`swfobject` is not a native JS object available in any browser. You need to include a file/JS script that holds definition of `swfobject`, I guess the file is named `swfobject.js`, look around your desk you will find it

Comment: check if the file is really included or not, better if you share the code in file as well